# Java: Set Different Object Fields Based On Array Size

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I have an object that has the following fields:

```
@Data
public class Person {
    private String code1;
    private String code2;
    private String code3;
    private String code4;
};
```

Then I need to set those code fields based on an input array size:

```
 if array has size 1, set code1
 if array has size 2, set code1, code2
 if array has size 3, set code1, code2, code3
 if array has size 4, set code1, code2, code3, code4
```

I did it using 4 `if` blocks. Is there a way to do it in a loop so that when there are more code fields to add, I don't need to keep adding the `if` block?  Thanks.

Comment: Does `Person` class provide setters for each field and has no-argument constructor?

Comment: @Pshemo yes it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid `if`s you can first create collection of setter calls via lambdas or method references and iterate over them depending on amount of data.

```
public class Demo {
    static List<BiConsumer<Person,String>> personSetters = List.of(
        (p, s) -> p.setCode1(s), //OR Person::setCode1,
        (p, s) -> p.setCode2(s), //OR Person::setCode2,
        (p, s) -> p.setCode3(s), //OR Person::setCode3,
        (p, s) -> p.setCode4(s)  //OR Person::setCode4
    );

    static Person createPersonFrom(String[] data){
        Person person = new Person();
        for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
            personSetters.get(i).accept(person, data[i]);
        }
        return person;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] data = {"val1","val2"};
        System.out.println(createPersonFrom(data));
    }
}
```

Output: `Person{code1='val1', code2='val2', code3='null', code4='null'}`

Comment: Thank you very much